# Get all Posts which have been tagged with any interest belonging to a user

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, relationships

I am making a site where after sign up the user chooses what their interests are. So the user only gets to see posts which are relevant to them. The relationship between the user and interests(in my case tags) is a many-to-many relationship through a join table. Also, a user can create a post  and add tags to the post. And a tag can have many posts. So the relationship between tags and posts is a many-to-many relationship trough a join table. In the `users` table I have a `tag_ids` column which stores a collection. Same thing with the `posts` table, I have a `tag_ids` column which stores a collection.

In my User model I have

```
has_many :user_tags
has_many :tags,:through => :user_tags
```

In my Post model I have

```
has_many :post_tags
has_many :tags,:through => :post_tags
```

If I did something like `current_user.tag_ids` I would get something like `[2, 3]`. And if I did sth like `Post.first.tag_ids` I get something like `[2, 4, 7]`. Hope you get the general picture. So how do I extract all the posts where either of the tag_ids for the current user is present in the posts tag_ids column using active record if it's possible. Thanks

Comment: Just to clarify, you're asking how to find the common tag_ids between the current_user.tag_ids and post.tag_ids?

Comment: Yeah then display all posts which have that tag_id with them

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way I can think of to do this is to simply query for both the current_user's and the Post's tag_ids, find any common tag_ids between the two, and the query your DB for the actual tags based on those ids. Here is a basic walkthrough of that:

```
# Get the current_user's tags
user_tags = current_user.tag_ids

# Map over all of the existing posts and grab all tag_ids
# Once you have them, flatten the result into a single array and make all values unique
post_tags = Post.all.map { |p| p.tag_ids }.flatten.uniq

# Find any common tags using '&'
common = user_tags & post_tags
```

You can then go over the resulting common array and find each relevant tag using the enumerator `.map` method:

```
# Map over common and find the relevant tags - return them in a new array
common.map do { |t_id| Tag.find(t_id) }
```

Which will get you the actual Tag objects.

Comment: I want to look inside the Posts model. Not a specific post. I used `Post.first.tag_ids` just to give you an insight of what is returned for just one record.  I want to get all posts then loop through them in the display page

Comment: So you want the common tags between the current_user's tag_ids and any tag_id across any existing post?

Comment: Yeahp...thats it...Would be glad if you can help me figure that out

Comment: @ChristopherVundi - edited my post. Will now find any common ids between all Posts and the current_user

Comment: Figured it out `@posts = Post.all.reject { |p| (p.tag_ids & @common).empty? }` , Thanks for helping me think it out though